# What is the correct way to write this in GSP?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm Using Grails 1.2.1, Groovy 1.7.7. For this line of code in a GSP ...

```
<g:if test="${not empty sessionScope.adminUser}">
```

I'm getting this error,

```
2011-03-21 09:15:38,960 [http-8080-5] ERROR StackTrace  - Sanitizing stacktrace:  
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, Users_davea_Documents_workspace_sts_2_6_0_SR1_socialmediaproxy_grails_app_views_index_gsp: 34: expecting ')', found 'empty' @ line 34, column 17.  
1 error
```

What is the correct syntax I should be using in my GSP file?  THanks, - Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work 
< g:if test="${sessionScope.adminUser}">

Comment: Thanks.  < g:if test="${session.adminUser}"> worked (Didn't realize the proper way to refer to a session was actually just "session"). - Dave

Answer (score 1):

Try `!empty` or simply `${sessionScope.adminUser}`